# Exponential decay for wave equation in even dimensions

Tags: sp.spectral-theory, wave-equation

Consider the wave equation
$$
  u_{tt} = \Delta_x u - q(x)u, \quad x \in\mathbb R^d, \; t > 0,\tag{1}\\
  u(0,x) = u_0(x) \in H^1_\text{comp}(\mathbb R^d),\\
  u_t(0,x) = u_1(x) \in L^2_\text{comp}(\mathbb R^d),
$$
where $q \in L^\infty_\text{comp}(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R)$. It is known that in odd dimensions $d$, if the operator $H=-\Delta+q(x)$ has no discrete spectrum and $0$ is not a resonance, then the solution $u$ decays exponentially on any compact set:
$$
  \|u(t,\cdot)\|_{H^2(\Omega)} \leq C_\Omega e^{-\gamma t}\bigl(\|u_0\|_{H^1(\mathbb R^d)} + \|u_1\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)} \bigr), \quad t \geq T,
$$
for any bounded domain $\Omega$, for some $C_\Omega$, $\gamma$, $T > 0$. This follows, in particular, from the resonance expansion of the solution $u$ (see, e.g., [Thm. 3.9, p. 99](http://math.mit.edu/~dyatlov/res/res_20171019.pdf) of these notes by Dyatlov-Zworski) and from the absense of real non-zero resonances due to Rellich's uniqueness theorem.

But what is the situation in even dimensions? Do we still have exponential decay when zero is not a resonance and the discrete spectrum of $H$ is empty?

Comment: Is the Laplacian positive or negative?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro In the current notation it is negative